# Atomically determine the "next" number in a MongoDB collection and assign it to a new document

Tags: python, mongodb, race-condition

Let's say I have a mongodb collection of the following layout:

```
{'number':1, '_id':...}
{'number':2, '_id':...}
{'number':4, '_id':...}
```

and so on.  As demonstrated, not all the numbers currently present have to be consecutive.

I want to write code which (a) determines what is the highest value for `number` found in collection and then (b) inserts a new document whose value for `number` is 1 higher than the current largest.

So if this is the only code that operates on the collection, no particular value for `number` should be duplicated.  The issue is that, done naively, this creates a race condition where two threads of this code running in parallel might find the same highest value and then insert the same next highest number twice.

So how would I do this atomically?  I'm working in Python, so I would prefer a solution in that language, but I will accept an answer that explains the concept in a way that can be adapted to any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine) does what you're looking for [in its SequenceField](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/fields.py#L1680).

Create a new collection called `indexes`. This collection will look like this:

```
[
    { '_id': 'mydata.number', 'next': 5 }
]
```

Whenever you'd like to get and set the next index, you simply use the following statement:

```
counter = collection.find_and_modify(
    query = { '_id': 'mydata.number' },
    update = { '$inc': { 'next': 1 } },
    new = True,
    upsert = True)
```

What this does is it finds and updates the sequence atomically in MongoDB and retrieves the next number. If the sequence doesn't exist, it is generated.

Thus, whenever you want to insert a new value into your collection, call the code above. If you want to maintain multple indexes across different collections and their fields, simply modify `mydata.number` to be another string referencing your "index."

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean transactional way to do this in MongoDB.  This is why there is the ObjectID datatype. http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html

Or you can utilize a unique key inside python using something like UUID: https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

Comment: Will MongoDB raise an error if I try and insert a value into a field with a unique index and that value already exists?  That is probably workable solution where I could catch the error and try again.